# Error while running Appium from windows power shell

Tags: selenium-webdriver, android-emulator, appium, appium-android

When I run appium using windows power shell, I get an error as below:

`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original err or: Could not find a connected Android device. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)`

But android studio is connected to the emulator. What could have potentially gone wrong?

I want to run the app in the emulator itself and I don't want to run in physical devices

Answer (score 0):

Run `adb devices` in your shell and make sure you got non-empty list and emulator is not marked 'offline'. If not, rebuild emulator or try with real device (just check developer options + USB debugging enabled in device settings)

Comment: I Run adb devices and shows an emulator. But still get same error while run appium using windows poweshell

Comment: 1)`npm appium-doctor -g` and run `appium-doctor --android` - make sure you got All Passed report.
2)Show capabilties you are using for Appium session creation and emulator config you use
3)Try alternatives: GenyMotion for personal use or real device. There might be your studio is not up-to-date and builds non-compatible emulator

Comment: "appium-doctor --android" command does not wokrd in windows power shell